# Passing parameter for a method in For Loop in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How pass a user parameter for example:

```
{% for document in documents %}
  {% for status in document.status_for user %}
      {{status}}     
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Generate A Exception:

> Exception Type:   TemplateSyntaxError Exception Value:     'for' statements
>   should use the format 'for x in y': for status in
>   document.status_for user

Easy Way for this?

EDIT:
Forgot one small detail, This is in the Loop!

Comment: You can't pass parameter to methods in django template.

Comment: =\ How something like {% url document_print document.id %} works?

Comment: try: `{% for status in user|document.status_for %}`

Comment: Logic must go into the view, not the template! add the result of document.status_for(user) into the context of your template.

Comment: @LuizCarvalho, that is not a variable but a tag

Comment: @karthikr no work `Invalid filter: 'document'`

Comment: @mawimawi Thanks, Do not know where his head was! is exactly this!

Comment: Forgot one small detail, This is in the Loop! =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manipulate your data before sending it to the template.

```
# views.py

    # ... inside view
    statuses = list()
    for document in documents:
         statuses.append( document.status_for(request.user) )

    return render_to_response('path/to/template.html', {'statuses': statuses}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in your template:

```
{% for status in statuses %}
    {{ status }}     
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [django template Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

> A variable can only be called if it has no required arguments. Otherwise, the system will return an empty string.

If you really want to do this, you can write [custom template filter or tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Or marshal the data in view appropriately then pass to template.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom template tags :

```
// In your app_folder/templatetags/custom_filter.py

@register.filter
def user_status(status, user):
    // Do work on these values
```

And use it in your view

```
{% for status in document.status_for %}
    {{status|user_status(user)}}     
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more informations about custom template tags in Django, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: Don't Work passing param with `{{status|user_status(user)}}`
tried:
`{{status|user_status:user}}`